# C# Building Web Socket Server

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm trying to build a WebSocket Server using C# i have been reading tutorials left right and centre to try and get this working.

So i'm using [Advanced Rest Client (ARC)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC) in in google chrome

to make the connection to my Server but it seems to hang at "Connecting to the remote server".

My Code for elevation to a WebSocket

```
Console.WriteLine("Connection Establised to: " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
// sets two streams
StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
// you could use the NetworkStream to read and write, 
// but there is no forcing flush, even when requested

Boolean bClientConnected = true;
String sData = null;

bool gotHeaders = false;
string headerBlock = "";
try
{
    while (!gotHeaders)
    {
        sData = sReader.ReadLine();
        headerBlock += sData + "\r\n";
        Console.WriteLine("Client << " + sData);
        if (headerBlock.Substring(headerBlock.Length - 4, 4) == "\r\n\r\n")
        {
            gotHeaders = true;
        }
    }
    string headerResponse = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
    + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
    + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
    + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
        SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(headerBlock).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
            )
        )
    ) + "\r\n\r\n";
    Console.WriteLine("Server >> HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
    + "Server >> Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
    + "Server >> Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
    + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(
        SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                new Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(headerBlock).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
            )
        )
    )
    + "\r\nServer >>\r\n");
    sWriter.WriteLine(headerResponse);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    bClientConnected = false;
    client.Close();
}

// to write something back.
while (bClientConnected)
{
    try
    {
        sData = sReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Client >> " + sData);
        sWriter.WriteLine("");
        sWriter.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        bClientConnected = false;
        client.Close();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Server output:

```
Connection Establised to: 127.0.0.1
Client << GET / HTTP/1.1
Client << Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Client << Connection: Upgrade
Client << Pragma: no-cache
Client << Cache-Control: no-cache
Client << Upgrade: websocket
Client << Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Client << Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Client << User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Client << Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Client << Accept-Language: en,nl;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Client << Sec-WebSocket-Key: tThSdzoXlh+jFiILH5pXSw==
Client << Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Client <<
Server >> HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Server >> Connection: Upgrade
Server >> Upgrade: websocket
Server >> Sec-WebSocket-Accept: DBANtxNFhA+xdRW4JFvwP1HwpHA=
Server >>
```

So my server is responding correctly and the client is not sending anything else to me i can't work out why it wont give me the console to send raw messages to my server.

Comment: Could you try adding a breakpoint or Console.WriteLine() into your second while loop, to make sure the line `sData = sReader.ReadLine();` is reached.

Comment: Also in `Try {} Catch {}` contruction (if you use them) always add output or throw exception, so you know that was exception

Comment: @Sergio i will be doing this is my just started work, i will be handling drops out properly I'm just trying to get it to work at the moment.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL it is deffinatly hitting the code all the way down to the while i have step though it from top to bottom it hits the while and waits at `sData = sReader.ReadLine();` inside the bottom `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was an annoyingly simple problem that caused so much trouble,

I was missing `sWriter.Flush();` after writing my headers.